# a simple exchange format for 2d vector paths

Tags: c#, format, 2d, autocad, cad

I am looking for a way to transfer simple 2d paths from a CAD program like AutoCAD to my program.

The format should be as simple as possible to parse.
The program is written in c#.
There will be one or at most very few paths per file, and the paths may be open or closed.

I have been looking into the standard CAD export formats.
IGES, EPS, DXF, PDF all are powerful enough, but the problem is that they are so much more powerful, and writing a converter than can extract path descriptions out of them would be a major undertaking.

The STL format would fit my needs exactly in its simplicity, except that it is only suitable for 3d surfaces, not 2d paths.

What is the standard way to get 2d paths from CAD programs?
Is there another format I have missed, or is there a .net library for any of these formats that can extract just the information I need?

Answer (score 1):

DXF is pretty easy to parse and you can skip most of the file content concentrating on the only entities you are interested in...

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised to find a free parser somewhere on the net for DXF. AutoCAD has been around for so long.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Alberto that DXF should be pretty easy to manage. It depends on how you want to use the information in your program (eg. are you going to draw it?)

When you say 2D paths I assume you mean polylines. An alternative would be to convert all the polylines to SVG.

You just need to parse each segment of the polyline and determine if it is a line or an arc. Then you need to convert the line or arc into the SVG string.

**Edit:**
This is really only feasible if you are writing an AutoCAD plugin to export your data. If you simply want to save an AutoCAD file using one of AutoCADs built in formats then DXF is probably the best option.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a standard data format like [STEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_10303) (STandard for the Exchange of Product model data) to extract data from your CAD tool.
There is an open source library [STEPcode](http://stepcode.org) written in C++.

Autocad shall export data to the STEP P21 format: see [this conversation](http://grabcad.com/questions/how-to-export-to-step-from-autocad).